# Russell & Norvig: Connecting models of probabilistic reasoning to Stochastic Differential Equations

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-differential-equations, kalman-filter, bayesian-network, hidden-markov-models

Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach, 4th Global ed.
by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig contains the following footnote on page 480 of chapter 14:

> Uncertainty over continuous time can be modeled by stochastic differential equations (SDEs). The models studied in this chapter can be viewed as discrete-time approximations to SDEs.

The chapter is on probabilistic reasoning over time and covers Hidden Markov Models, Kalman Filters and Dynamic Bayesian Networks.

In light of the footnote; could someone please explain the connections these models have to SDEs and/or possibly provide some relevant references?

Comment: Can you give a specific example from the book?